# Collatz conjecture sequence length using a python generator

Tags: python, algorithm, sequences

I am trying to find the length of a Collatz conjecture sequence given by the following algorithm:

[image]

The code that I am running with is:

```
def get_count(n):
    i = 1
    while n != 1:
        (n, i) = (3*n+1 if n%2 else n/2, i + 1)
    return i
```

Can I implement the same using a python generator? And would using the generator be an improvement for implementing the algorithm, performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator version:

```
def get_count(n):
    i = 1
    while n != 1:
        (n, i) = (3*n+1 if n%2 else n/2, i + 1)
        yield (n, i)

# usage:  
g = get_count(3)
for x in g:
    print x
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(10, 2)
(5, 3)
(16, 4)
(8, 5)
(4, 6)
(2, 7)
(1, 8)
```

Using a generator in this case will not improve anything since the final result is stored in `i` only when you reach `n == 1` (the last iteration).

Using generators has a meaning when each iteration provides a substantial result which can be used in later calls ("kind of" like dynamic programming). So, for example, if you want to calculate `factorial(n)` but you also want to know the results of `factorial(k)` for every `k < n` - then it makes sense to use a generator.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I implement the same using a python generator?

Yes, you could yield each successive value. Then you could apply [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) on the generator function. Then you could use [this piece of code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to find the length of the iterator.

> And would using the generator be an improvement for implementing the algorithm, performance wise?

Slower I think because some other code is used to process the generator, creating overhead.

P.S. Instead of incrementing `i` in a while-loop, use `for i in`[itertools.count](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)`(1)` (itertools.count is the same thing as range except the stop value is infinite).